# The collection with url was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, sql-server-express

Hi I am working on TFS Migration form on-premises to VSTS online and also I am Upgrade the my TFS Server as a new Version.
 Here I am Facing the problem is when I am running the validation commend in Command Prompt I am getting the below exception and I am passing the command is like below

> TfsMigrator validate /collection:http://desktop-qvs5g7f:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

when I am running the above command I am getting the below exception

> The collection with url was not found: 'http://desktop-qvs5g7f:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection'

and with in the Log folder it creates one log description like in the below

> TfsMigrator  validate /collection:http://desktop-qvs5g7f:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection

```
Connection string not specified, trying to use the one from the Application Tier's web.config

Using the framework connection string Data Source=DESKTOP-QVS5G7F\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Tfs_Configuration;Integrated Security=True

Exception Message: The collection with url was not found: 'http://desktop-qvs5g7f:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection' (type ArgumentException)

Exception Stack Trace:   at    TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommand.CreateCollectionRequestContext(String collectionUrl)
                      at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunValidations(Boolean validateFiles)
                      at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunImpl()
                      at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommand.Run()
```

For the above exception how to resolve that and for the validation Commands I am following the below URL as Reference is

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/migration-import

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? I tried the tool https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274 on my TFS 2015.3 AT machine, and get a successful validation. You may try url http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection or http://ipaddress:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection to see whether you'll validate the url.